# Display a dynamic list of all document libraries in a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, content-query-web-part

I am using a Content Query web part to display a list libraries in a specific site, this works like a charm. The only question is how would I sort the results of libraries alphabetically? HELP!

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode of content query web part, have you tried the "Sort items by" in "Presentation"?

[image]

If the results are sorted by "Title" then the documents having blank title will come up no matter what the document name is. Try removing the result limit to see this in action.

Comment: Is this answer still suitable for SharePoint Online?